# Removing dictionary from list of dictionaries if some value is equal 0

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
result = [{'Prudence': 1, 'PVP': 215.0, 'OFF': 172.0}, {'Temperance': 0, 'PVP': 185.0, 'OFF': 148.0}, {'Humility': 1, 'PVP': 175.0, 'OFF': 140.0}, {'Faith': 0, 'PVP': 165.0, 'OFF': 132.0}, {'Charity': 0, 'PVP': 155.0, 'OFF': 124.0}, {'Courage': 1, 'PVP': 285.0, 'OFF': 228.0}]
```

and I want to obtain a list of dictionaries that value of each keys is not equal 0 like this:

```
final_result=[{'Prudence': 1, 'PVP': 215.0, 'OFF': 172.0}, {'Humility': 1, 'PVP': 175.0, 'OFF': 140.0}, {'Courage': 1, 'PVP': 285.0, 'OFF': 228.0}]
```

I tried to use for but I have not the final_result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a comprehension based on `any()`:; `[item for item in result if not any(v==0 for v in item.values())]`

Comment: The `all()` equivalent is also fine: `[item for item in result if all(v!=0 for v in item.values())]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = [{'Prudence': 1, 'PVP': 215.0, 'OFF': 172.0}, {'Temperance': 0, 'PVP': 185.0, 'OFF': 148.0}, {'Humility': 1, 'PVP': 175.0, 'OFF': 140.0}, {'Faith': 0, 'PVP': 165.0, 'OFF': 132.0}, {'Charity': 0, 'PVP': 155.0, 'OFF': 124.0}, {'Courage': 1, 'PVP': 285.0, 'OFF': 228.0}]

final_result = [entry for entry in result if all(value != 0 for value in entry.values())]

print(final_result)
```

Output:

```
[{'Prudence': 1, 'PVP': 215.0, 'OFF': 172.0}, {'Humility': 1, 'PVP': 175.0, 'OFF': 140.0}, {'Courage': 1, 'PVP': 285.0, 'OFF': 228.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go over each item and check its keys, if any is 0 remove the whole item:

```
for item in result:
    if all(item[key] != 0 for key in item.keys()):
        final_result.append(item)
```

at the and the result will contain the values you wanted

Comment: When you remove an item from the list (result.remove(item)), it alters the length of the list, which affects the loop. This can cause skipping elements or not properly iterating over all elements.

Comment: Output of this will be : [{'Prudence': 1, 'PVP': 215.0, 'OFF': 172.0}, {'Humility': 1, 'PVP': 175.0, 'OFF': 140.0}, {'Charity': 0, 'PVP': 155.0, 'OFF': 124.0}, {'Courage': 1, 'PVP': 285.0, 'OFF': 228.0}] ..... which is not expected as 'Charity': 0' included.

Comment: Please add some detail of what your code is doing.

Comment: @letmedownslowly the detailed explanation is there, read it carefully please